# Input en variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que tengo que, en el mismo php, procesar información de un formulario. Tengo una caja de texto y un boton. En el botón llamo a una función javascript que, a su vez, llama  a una función php, tengo que tratar la información del formulario y dependiendo de que se halla obtenido, hacer una cosa u otra.  Necesito saber a una variable de php ($usuario , por ejemplo) que obtenga el valor de un texto.

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="Insertar" onclick="Comprobar();"
```

JAVASCRIPT

> function Comprobar(){
>
> ```
>         alert('hola');
>         alert('<?php echo ComprobarPHP(); ?>');
>
>     }
> ```

PHP

> ```
>  <?php
>             function ComprobarPHP()
>             {
>                 $nombre = "";
>             }
>
>             ?>
> ```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es confusa. Por ejemplo, ¿qué justifica que tengas que usar variables del servidor (PHP)  en el cliente (Javascript)? Sería bueno que lo expliques, para poder sugerirte una solución óptima basada en Ajax por ejemplo, si es que realmente necesitas una comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor.

Comment: Efectivamente como bien te comentan mezclas conceptos. Yo te aconsejaría que primero aprendieras a trabajar con php + html, luego javascrit + html y finalmente veas como hacer cosas que involucren a los dos.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos entornos de ejecución cuando desarrollas una aplicación web:

- La parte del servidor: Es en la que se ejecuta PHP. A la programación que se enfoca en este entorno se le llama `backend`.
- La parte del navegador( o, normlamente, llamada `cliente` ): Es en la que se renderiza HTML y CSS y dónde se ejecuta JavaScript. A la programación que se enfoca en este entorno se llama `frontend`.

Una función de un entorno no puede llamar a una función de otro entorno. Es decir, una función JavaScript( cliente ) no puede llamar a una función PHP( servidor ). Ni a la inversa.

Por tanto, tu enfoque del problema es inadecuado. Puedes obtener más información desde el enlace: [Front-end y back-end - Wikipedia, la enciclopedia libre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_y_back-end)

Comment: Pero los que explicas no impide que haya comunicación entre ambos entornos de ejecución. Te invito a leer mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero:

Tu función PHP debe retornar un resultado en un formato (JSON por ejemplo):

**comprobar.php**

```
function ComprobarPHP() {
  $nombre = "";
  return ($nombre == "" ? true : false);
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo ComprobarPHP();
```

Segundo:
Entonces ya podrás invocar a esa funcion mediante javascript por AJAX.

```
function Comprobar() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'comprobar.php?dato=valor');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      alert(xhr.responseText ? 'VERDAD' : 'FALSO');
    } else {
      alert('Error: ' + xhr.status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

O también con jQuery:

```
function Comprobar() {
  alert('hola');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'comprobar.php',
    data: {dato: 'valor'}
  }).done(function(resultadoJSON) {
    alert(resultadoJSON ? 'VERDAD' : 'FALSO');
  });
}
```

Nota que en la funcion Comprobar() de javascript, incluso puedes mandar otros datos necesarios para la función ComprobarPHP() de PHP, tanto por POST o por GET.

Comment: En la pregunta podemos apreciar onclick="Comprobar();", lo que nos da indicios de que no se está utilizando JQuery, por lo cual tu respuesta no funcionará a menos que especifiques como incluir JQuery.